# Failed to load /Users/sajad/.gemrc Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Every time I try create new rails application, before start install gem 
show this line :

```
Failed to load /Users/sajad/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash
```

How to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `rm -f /Users/sajad/.gemrc`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I corrected a typo and changed your title a little bit. Good luck!